# PostgreSQL user password reset

Tags: postgresql, change-password, forgot-password

I've forgot my PostgreSQL password. I'm using MacOS Catalina. I'm following those [instructions](http://cli23.blogspot.com/2013/12/resetting-postgresql-postgres-user.html)

When I try accessing the file it with `sudo vi /Library/PostgreSQL/11/data/pg_hba.conf` it gives me an empty file. When I try to get to the directory I cannot access data folder to see if there is such file there.

Comment: "When I try to get to the directory I cannot access data folder to see if there is such file there."  Why not?  Did you get an error?  Is there no such folder?

Comment: There is a folder, but it says permission denied. I've tried with sudo, but the same

Comment: How can permission be denied to sudo?  Please show the exact command.